# Modal Bootstrap User Confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How can I create a JQuery function that waits till user confirms whether or not he really wants to delete data.

How can I achieve something like this:

```
function UserConfirmation()
{
  ShowModal();    //"Global" Delete Confirmation Bootstrap Modal
  //Now wait till the user decides whether or not he really wants to 
  //delete data(Button events or on Modal hide).
  //On user reply:
  if(UserReplied == 'Delete')
  {}
  else
  {} 
}
```

**Edit:**

This is the html code for Modal in Layout. This ModalDelete would be called through ShowModal() function whenever need be.

```
<!-- Delete Data Confirmation Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalDelete" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" id="btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" id="btn-delete" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The function UserConfirmation listens to Modal events after calling ShowModal() and on button press or modal hide would proceed depending on user's choice.

I think this can be achieved through promise or deffered action.

Comment: Where is the data stored?

Comment: Modal html is designed into the Layout. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: from where you are getting the value for `UserReplied ` . and can you provide a fiddle

Comment: That is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Btw I wonder why I am getting downvotes?!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is how I solved the question using promise with Jquery deferred:

1. This function listens till the user clicks on a button in #ModalDelete and returns the id of the button clicked.

   ```
   function ModalOptionChoosen() {

   var deferred = $.Deferred();

   $('#ModalDelete button').on('click', function (e) {
       var $target = $(e.target); // Clicked button element
       $(this).closest('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
           //console.log($target); // Logged if the clicked button actually closed the modal
           var result = $target.attr('id');
           deferred.resolve(result);
       });
   });

   return deferred.promise();
   };
   ```
2. While another function waits for the promise from above ModalOptionChoosen() to be returned.

   ```
   function ShowModalWaitForResult () {
       ShowModal();

       var promise = ModalOptionChoosen();
       promise.done(function (result) {
           console.log(result); // log the user selected value
       });
   });
   ```

Now I can reference ModalOptionChoosen function anywhere if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog for example and then something like this whenever you need delete confirmation:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Alert',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this ?',
        buttons: [{
            label: 'Yes',
            cssClass: 'btn-danger',
            action: function(dialog) {
                dialog.close();
                //your action
            }
        }, {
            label: 'No',
            action: function(dialog) {
                dialog.close();
            }
        }]
    });`
```